# Como impedir o carregamento de imagens GIF e só autoriza-lo ao clicar num botão?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Titulo auto-explicativo "Como impedir o carregamento de imagens GIF e só autoriza-lo ao clicar num botão?".

Comment: http://embed.ly/docs/tutorials/gif

Comment: Nesse  [LINK](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6457/como-posso-pausar-e-dar-play-em-um-gif) existe uma pergunta parecida, pode servir como referência.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o **[freezeframe](http://freezeframe.chrisantonellis.com/)** para tal, a outra forma de fazer é ter uma imagem estática do gif animado, e via jQuery fazer a troca das imagens.

Ficaria desta forma utilizando duas imagens:

***JQuery***

```
$(function(){
   $("img").click(function(){
      var gif = $(this).data('animate');
      $(this).attr('src', gif);
   });
});
```

***HTML***

```
<img src="/static/88855445.jpg" data-animate="/gif/88855445.gif" alt="" />
```

Ao clicar na imagem ele irá "iniciar" o GIF