# Botão Play e Pause em animação de imagens usando Javascript em HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<style type='text/css'>
    #animation img{
        display: none;
    }
    #animation img:first-child{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    onload = function startAnimation(){
        var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
        var frameCount = frames.length;
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
        frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
            frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
        }, 100);
        stop;
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<div id="animation">
    <img src="cyanblue.png"/>
    <img src="canvas2.png"/>
</div>
```

Como eu troco essa função onload para uma onclick de modo que ao clicar em um botão `Play(input button #1)`, ele inicie a animação, e ao clicar em outro botão `Pause(input button #2)` ele pare a animação, de tal forma que ao executar a função `Pause`, ele pare exatamente no frame que estava sendo exibido, e que ao ser clicado no botão de `Play`, ele continue exatamente a partir do frame exibido após a função Pause ter sido executada?

Comment: Relacionada (e pode ser útil pra vc): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6457/como-posso-pausar-e-dar-play-em-um-gif/6550#6550

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type='text/css'>
    #animation img{
        display: none;
    }
    #animation img:first-child{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
     function startAnimation(){
        var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
        var frameCount = frames.length;
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
        frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
            frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
        }, 100); 
        stop;           
    }       
    //]]>
</script>
<div id="animation">
    <img src="cyanblue.png"/>
    <img src="canvas2.png"/>
</div>
<button onclick="startAnimation()">Clique aqui!</button>
```

Isso vai resolver.

Comment: Obrigado, o código funcionou bem! mas como eu faço pra pausar?

Comment: Coloquei a parte do codigo para pausar, imagino que seja assim uma vez que não conheço o plugin de vc ta usando para rodar o video.

Comment: a parte da Stopfunction não funcionou aqui, e não é bem um vídeo, mas duas imagens.

Comment: Na verdade supostamente ele deveria parar sozinho. Se conseguir reproduzir no jsfiddle fica mais facil de ajudar.

Comment: aqui tem um exemplo, mas a stop function não parece funcionar nele. http://jsfiddle.net/k2Ljnrky/6/

Comment: @Rick, tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas alterações nesse jsFiddle, veja se lhe serve. Aqui o play e o pause funcionam perfeitamente. http://jsfiddle.net/k2Ljnrky/11/

Comment: perfeitamente o que eu queria, mas perdão incomodar, mas só me resta uma dúvida.
aquelas 'var src' do javascript devem permanecer ali ou tem alguma maneira de trabalhar o mesmo resultado dessa fiddle com as imagens em html tags img?

Comment: na verdade é diferente a forma q ele fez e a sua, no caso dele é uma tag img com um "src" source, e o javascript muda esse source passando imagem por imagem do array na variavel a cima do codigo. no seu caso, ele carrega todas as imagens dentro da div cada uma com a sua "src" e todas elas com "display none" e o javascript vai dando display block em 1 por 1, eu prefiro a abordagem dele pois ela da a possibilidade de mudar a fonte facilmente adcionando novas imagens e ela pode rodar infinitamente. a sua ela vai rodar 1 vez e as imagens vao 1 sobrepondo a outra e qndo acabar acabou rs. abç